# empty bags that authorities suspect [were] used to hold

Tags: phrase-meaning

The following is from the CNN news of today.
I wonder if "were" is mistakenly omitted between "suspect" and "used." 
Am I in the wrong?

> A number of used syringes, prescription drugs and empty bags that authorities suspect used to hold heroin also were found in the apartment where Hoffman, 46, was found dead Sunday.

Answer (score 4):

No: *used to* is used to indicate something that was the case in the past but no longer is. The bags are suspected to have held heroin the past, but contained none when they were found.

[English Grammar Secrets](http://www.englishgrammarsecrets.com/usedto/menu.php) has a useful page which was a high-ranking result in a Google search.

That said, including *were* as you suggest is also valid in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Not necessarily. The writer could have meant that the bags held heroin at some time in the past but did so no longer ('they used to hold heroin'). But, yes, it is just as possible that it should have been *were used*.

Answer (score 1):

Both are possible, and while not identical, in this case have pretty much the same implication.

The sentence as it is describes the state (in the past) of the bags. If you add "were" the relative clause turns into a passive construction: The bags were used (by someone) to hold drugs.

You can simplify the sentences to:

> The bags used to hold the heroin.
>
> The bags were used to hold the heroin.

and compare the meaning. Another example which might show the difference clearer:

> The key used to open the door. (but now it's rusted and doesn't work any longer - a past state is being described)
>
> The key was used to open the door. (as a result of the key being used, the door changed state from being closed to being open - a past action is being described)

Answer (score 0):

At least in my dialect, the pronunciation of "used" in "used to" (yo̅o̅st) is quite different from the pronunciation of "used" in "were used" (yo̅o̅zd).

Comment: This is true of more or less all dialects (that I know of), but it does not answer the question—since the source is written, no inferences can be made from pronunciation.

Comment: I did not assume the source was written. "..from the CNN news of today" could mean the OP heard a news reader speaking, or it could mean it was read from a crawler line on a cable TV broadcast, or it could refer to a web page.